ngcc error while run `ng build` with Angular18
Package subpath './ngcc' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/xxx/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/package.json imported from /Users/xxx/node_modules/ng-packagr/lib/utils/ng-compiler-cli.js
anyone has idea about this error?

As stated in this article:

ngcc is a tool used to compile Angular libraries that have been published in the legacy format, which is not compatible with the Angular Ivy runtime, to a format that is compatible with Ivy

This error is caused because ngcc support has been dropped in Angular 16 so any dependency to it would break.
You may have this error if you use an outdated library using Angular View Engine.
